# Write clang compiler diagnostics to a structured file

Tags: clang

What is the best way to get the emitted compilation warnings and errors in a structured format (e.g. XML file, or similar) when using clang?

I'm aware of the command line option --serialize-diagnostics, but the serialized data format is binary and I found no description how to decode it.

My other option would be to write a clang plugin that can emit the warnings and errors by itself into e.g. XML.

What other options I have? Text parsing is not an option for me, I'd need the structured data right from clang.

Comment: Re-asked over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657869/how-do-i-dump-gcc-warnings-into-a-structured-format but in relation to gcc ...