# Looking for GCC error output documentation

Tags: gcc

I am trying to automate a build process using GCC and am able to redirect the error messages to a file for further processing. As of now, I have to parse the entire message to pick out the information I need about what type of an error it is.

Can anyone tell me if the messages have a standardised code? For e.g. XXYY for an undeclared variable or YXYX for a struct missing a member etc and if GCC can be parametrised to include those in the output?

Also, where can I find the text of all possible error messages that GCC (cc1 to be precise) can generate. I am assuming that this should be available in the sources but I lack even the faintest idea of where to get started. Maybe someone with a lot more idea about the GCC can help me here.

Comment: Unlike e.g. MSVC, GCC doesn't have "codes" for their error messages. Also, many error messages comes with informational notes, that are needed to fully understand the error, so picking out just the actual error message itself isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have come across .po files which are used for translating error messages to other langugaes. One essentially replaces the text output from the original source files. Theoretically, I could write a .po file which outputs a code per message and the necessary information for that error. Am I correct?

Comment: You could try [-fdiagnostics-format=json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220081/1983398).

Comment: That does give machine parseable output. I can use that as a starting point.